# Log to grunt from other file

Tags: node.js, logging, gruntjs

I'm using a grunt plugin,`grunt-casper`, to allow me to use CasperJS to run some web crawling tasks.

However, the way the plugin works is that it runs `casperjs file.js` on the files you specify in the task options.

I want to be able to log output from the `file.js`, and I can using `console.log` -- that shows up in Terminal. I can't do that, however, with `grunt.log('test');` (unsurprisingly, I don't have access to the grunt variable.  Any suggestions?